# PowerShell Script for Obtaining Specific System Info from Network Computers

Tags: powershell, networking

Wondering if anyone has a PS script to grab every Computer Name, Service Tag, CPU, RAM, Total and Free Disk Space on a network.

I've tried some code I've found here and TechNet, but doesn't consistently give me what I need or there's too much to decipher.

Comment: that is a very, VERY common thing to do ... so a quick net search otta show you lots of examples. here is the one i usually use `[PowerShell] basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH`

Comment: Please post examples of what you've tried so far, and what didn't work so that we can help guide you to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install PSINFO and in a command line, use

```
 psinfo \\"computer name goes here" -d
```

That will give you computer name, service tag, CPU, CPU speed, and total and free disk space.

For the rest, I'm not sure.